# CSS Font Rendering Issue

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

I am developing a website. I'm using a google font to style my page. But it's not displaying correctly. I've read up a bit on faux fonts, but I believe that only applies when the font that is needed is not supplied. I've imported my google font, code is

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Titillium WebSemiBold'), local('TitilliumWeb-SemiBold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v1/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wprx7IBmrqA5IG9z8WNe77b9o.woff) format('woff');
}
```

My CSS for the font is

```
font-size:30px;
font-family: 'Titillium Web';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
```

But I believe it's displaying a faux font. Here's the difference between an image of what it should look like on the left, and what it's displaying on the right.

[My problem http://resource.theboulderdesign.com/400/homebox/gettingcompare.png](http://resource.theboulderdesign.com/400/homebox/gettingcompare.png)

I hope someone can solve my problem.

Morgan Kenyon

Comment: Which browsers did you test in?  Also when I've used CSS3 fonts before I had to specify in a variety of formats for various browsers. I admit I'm less familiar with Google's fonts though.

Comment: Chrome is the worst, that's what the picture is in.

In IE and Firefox it looks a lot better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Chrome/Windows problem. It'll affect the font thickness and letter spacing, but you can add a white `text-stroke` to smooth it out:

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
-webkit-text-fill-color: white;
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zzmbu/**

Here's a screenshot of it:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I've also found that if you add

```
text-shadow:0px 0px #FF0000;
```

property to my CSS, it renders correctly. I don't know why though.